# How to store data from string into array with delimiter

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [separate the ids and store in two different array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206312/separate-the-ids-and-store-in-two-different-array)

```
String response=@" hr 123,124,125,126,127,128 hr st 234,235,236,237 st";
```

from hr to hr i need to store in one array.

from st to st i need to store in another array.

My service provider is playing with response.....

Please help me out.

Comment: have you tried NSScanner for this?

Comment: yeap  Aravindhanarni its working nsscanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
    NSMutableString *response = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @" hr 123,124,125,126,127,128 hr st 234,235,236,237 st"];

    [response replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                              withString:@"" 
                                 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, [response length])];




    NSRange firstAppearanceOfHr = [response rangeOfString:@"hr"];

    [response replaceCharactersInRange:firstAppearanceOfHr withString:@""];



    NSRange secondAppearanceOfHr = [response rangeOfString:@"hr"];

    NSString *hrString = [response substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, secondAppearanceOfHr.location)];

    NSArray *hrArray = [hrString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    NSLog(@"HrArray:%@",[hrArray description]);

    NSRange firstAppearaceOfSt = [response rangeOfString:@"st"];

    NSInteger startSt = firstAppearaceOfSt.location+firstAppearaceOfSt.length;
    NSString *stString  = [response substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startSt, [response length] - startSt - 2)];

    NSArray *stArray = [stString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    NSLog(@"StArray:%@",[stArray description]);
```

Comment: [mutableResponse replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,mutableResponse.length)];

Comment: this is replace it crashing saying bad access

Comment: lonut alexandru..... Thanks a lot.... Its now working